# Is strcpy_s part of the C++ Standard? Or only part of MS Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, strcpy, tr24731

Using the function `strcpy` in MS Visual Studio gives me an error saying I should use `strcpy_s` which is safer to use. Is `strcpy_s` part of the C++ standard? Or is it only part of Microsoft Visual C++?

Will code containing `strcpy_s` only compile in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy_s()` is an optional part of C11 (more formally called a "conditional feature".  Implementations are permitted to not implement the "Bounds-checking interfaces" standardized in Annex K.

Some other conditional features of C11 include:

- atomics
- complex types
- threads
- variable length arrays (the interesting this about this is that VLAs were not optional in C99)

Comment: I see. I have only learned C++ and not C, do most things in the C standard also apply to C++? If so, does that mean that many C++ features are not mentioned in the C++ standard because they were already described in the C standard?

Comment: C++11 and C++14 refer to the C99 standard.  As far as I know this is still the case in the most recent draft of what's supposed to be C++17.  I don't know if there are plans to update C++17 to refer to C11 or not.  But even if they do the bounds-checking interfaces would presumably still be optional.  As far as I know, the glibc developers are not inclined to implement Annex K. Ulrich Drepper has posted quite negatively about it in the past.