# Visual studio doesn't support strcpy_s function in C

Tags: c++, visual-studio, error-handling, c-strings, strcpy

I'm new to C++ and currently using Visual Studio for coding. My `strcpy_s()` does not work for some reason

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

int main(){
    char a[]="Hello World!";
    strcpy_s(a+6,"C++");
    std::cout<<a;
}
```

This programme should print "Hello C++", however it does not.

I tried other editors (including online C++ IDE) and this issue is fixed. Is there a way to fix this problem in Visual Studio?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code has _undefined behavior_. Also `strcpy_s()` is not a standard function, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491687/is-strcpy-s-part-of-the-c-standard-or-only-part-of-ms-visual-c

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy.  And I'm surprised the code even compiles.

Comment: @paul sorry just realize that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No worries

Comment: You need `#include <string.h>`. Note that [`strcpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) requires the the size of the destination (`destsz`) as a 2nd argument.

Comment: If the compiler says `strcpy is depreceated, use strcpy_s instead`, the solution is not to add an `_s` to the call, but to disable the warning [How to use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450423/how-to-use-crt-secure-no-warnings)

Comment: The 'deprecation' of the totally standard C/C++ function `strcpy` is something that only exists in Microsoft's imagination. That said you should not be using this function and other C-style string functions. You should use the C++ string class `std::string` instead. Any learning resource that begins your C++ journey by teaching you about C strings is not worth pursuing.

Comment: I think it's clear what happened here, you started with a completely correct program using `strcpy`, then you unfortunately followed Microsoft's advice (and followed it incorrectly) and ended up with an incorrect program using `strcpy_s`. I would go back to `strcpy` or better still find a better tutorial for C++.

Comment: Where are you learning C++ from, because it seems an outdated source that tries to teach you "C". Anyway your writing to memory that is not yours (not allocated)

Comment: @PepijnKramer It's OK to write to `a`, but I'm not sure what `strcpy_s` will make of `a + 6`

Comment: strcpy_s requires an additional argument, the size of the buffer where you write. The correct line should read
    strcpy_s ((a + 6), (sizeof (a) - 6), "C++");

Answer (score 0):

[strcpy_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s?view=msvc-170&devlangs=cpp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(STRING%252Fstrcpy_s)%3Bk(strcpy_s)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue#parameters) requires dest_size. The behavior of strcpy_s is undefined if the source and destination strings overlap.

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    char a[] = "Hello World!";  
    strcpy_s(a + 6, strlen("C++")+1, "C++");
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Possible output:
Hello C++

Another solution:

```
#include<iostream>


int main() {
    char a[] = "Hello World!";  
    char b[20];
    strncpy_s(b, sizeof(b), a, 6);
    strcat_s(b, sizeof(b), "C++");
    std::cout << b;
}
```